# Local port forwarding using SSH only works from some machines

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, port-forwarding, jupyter

I am setting up an SSH server on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. I am trying to use the server for remotely accessing Jupyter Notebook.

For that purpose, I have downloaded an opens-server package. I set up Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW) to allow for SSH connection on desired port.

From any machine, a **simple connection request works perfectly fine**:

```
ssh -v -p [PORT] [USER]@[IP_ADDRESS]
```

However, when **running an SSH command with a request to forward** jupyter's interface to the local machine **works on one Mac computer but not others I have tried**:

```
ssh -v -Nfg -L 8888:localhost:9999 -p [PORT] [USER]@[IP-ADDRESS]
```

Which produces the following error, even though I enter the same password as previously:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I have tried playing around with ***sshd_config*** but to no avail. What could be the reason for the fact that ssh with port forwarding request works from certain machines but not others?

Comment: Suggestion from someone who has done this very thing to access a Jupyter Notebook remotely:  Remove the `-Nfg` options from your ssh command and try it.  In my experience it will work, though you'll have the ssh command still in the foreground.  Now add those three options back, one at a time, until you find the one that's giving you trouble, and you can focus on why it's a problem and how to solve/work-around it.

Comment: Why are you setting anything up on a machine running an almost 6 years old release of Ubuntu? Even though that was an LTS release support (unless you pay for ir) ended last year.